# Exibir 2 dataTextField em um SelectList

Tags: c#, mvc, lista

Ola! Estou com um probleminha para fazer um selectlist exibir 2 valores no textfield. 
Tenho o seguinte SelectList que está armazenado em uma viewbag:

```
ViewBag.Account = new SelectList(new AccountBusiness().GetList<Account>(Util.AuxiliaryMethods.BMPerRequestInstance).ToList(), "AccountId", "AccountNumber");
```

No DOM ele exibe o AccountNumber no texto do Option e o AccountId no seu value. Na tela ele exibe da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso que ele exiba em vez de apenas o AccountNumber, exiba também mais um campo, que é o Description, então ficaria o AccountNumber + Description, mais ou menos assim "15252 - Standart", e no value continuaria retornando o Id. Como posso fazer o SelectList receber dois parametros ?

Comment: Poderia concatenar a propriedade `Description` com um separador e depois ao obter o valor fazia um _split_ pelo caracter separador (pode ser "-" ou ";").

Comment: O valor que seria o Id eu ja to obtendo pelo Value do option, então o texto que eu colocar no option não vai fazer diferença. Então acho que não teria necessidade de dar um split pra pegar ele depois, é que to pegando  o id pelo javascript. Mas sobre concatenar, faço antes de mandar pro selectlist ou depois ?

Comment: Penso que seria no `SelectList` diretamente.

Comment: Mas como faria isso ? Tentei fazer ele passar tipo 2 campos, utilizando + "-" + mas ele entende como se fosse o nome do campo. Se eu jogar la "AccountNumber" + "-" + "Description" ele procura exatamente esse campo. Não manjo muito de concatenação como pode ver huahua se puder me ajudar com exemplo de codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta você popular o seu `SelectList()` com uma `List<SelectListItem>` ou compor outro objeto com estrutura fornecendo os valores que serão utilizados para as propriedades `Value` e `Text`.

```
var selectAccounts = new AccountBusiness()
                            .GetList<Account>(Util.AuxiliaryMethods.BMPerRequestInstance)
                            .Select(x => new { Value = x.AccountId, Text = string.Format("{0} - {1}", x.AccountNumber, x.Description})
                            .ToList();
ViewBag.Account = new SelectList(selectAccounts, "Value", "Text"));
```

Comment: Ha, ia responder mesmo isso, por pouco :)

Comment: Agradeço brother ! Ele no caso retornou isso na dropdownlist "{ Value = 1, Text = 15252 - Standart }" , mas funciona, pega o Description e o Accountnumber, só vou ver um jeito de jogar o value no value do option. Valeu mano!

Comment: Veja minha edição, acho que agora está mais claro.

Comment: Eu tinha esquecido de declarar os atributos, uma vez que utilizei um objeto simples e não do tipo `SelectListItem`